# Flutter) How can I retrieve certain value from Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

1. I am using 'Firebase Realtime Database' for retrieving some data in my Flutter app.
2. the data is structured like a picture on below.

[image]

3. What I want is creating lists consists of each upper child.(e.g.  `[central][2] = "test-2"`  `[central][3] = ""`  `[central][4] = "test-4"`)
4. But I keep getting indivisible values like this picture below. I also tried to separate value from `snapshot.value` using `ToList()`, but it failed.

[image]

5. code

```dart
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class GetMealScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GetMealScreenState createState() => _GetMealScreenState();
}

class _GetMealScreenState extends State<GetMealScreen> {

  DatabaseReference itemRef5 = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("central");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Example"),
        ),
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
                  query: itemRef5, // use this just for test
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                      Animation<double> animation, int index) {

                    return Container(
                        child:
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                                snapshot.value.toString()
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                    );
                  }
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

I've been trying to solve this problem by searching and modify codes but keep failed.. Is there any solution for this?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: By any chance - can the data be in English? It's really hard to debug this way.

Comment: @frunkad Sorry, I just edited code and pics in English. Could you check this again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase RTDB does not support queries that match for inequality or filter out empty value. It needs to be done on the frontend display side. But in your scenario the exact query needs to be passed to [FirebaseAnimatedList](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/ui_firebase_animated_list/FirebaseAnimatedList-class.html), this makes it a bit cumbersome.

Reading the docs, it doesn't look there's an easy method to do further filter the query (maybe checking in `itemBuilder` and sending null might work - I haven't tested that).

In either scenario, the best method is to ensure your data is not structured in that format in the first place. A simple [database rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) should work.